# How many pages can I continuously print without damaging the printer?

Tags: printer

I have a Brother HL 5340D printer. I have around 6-7000 pages to print.

I want to know how many pages I can print continuously. Will it heat up?

Comment: You may want to consider a printing service.  Once you consider the cost of toner, paper, time and wear-and-tare on the printer the service could be cheaper.  They should be able to take care of the large page volume in a short time and even bind it for you.

Comment: In my country for printing and binding of 300pages ebook they cost 35$. so for 6000 pages the cost will be 700$.
I got printer (349$ + BInder 300$ + Binding sheets,combs(50$) + paper(4*12 ~50$). Toner 400g(60$ prints 12000pages). Is'nt that good

Comment: @Mirage So what was the state of your printer after the batch prints?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be fine!

In general the main thing that heats up in a laser printer is called the fuser. The fuser usually accounts for the majority of a laser printer's power usage. The heat of the fuser, under substandard conditions, can definitely cause damage to interior parts, **however** newer printers will usually have a good ventilation system to aid in heat dissipation. Another feature of newer printers is a power saving feature which will turn off the fuser and let it cool down. The printer only starts up again after proper working temperature is reached. You'll know if you have this feature or not If you've ever printed 100 pages or so. The stops are very noticeable but at least you know it's for safety reasons.

The HL 5340D specifically is from early 2009 I believe. It more than likely has these features and then some. You can even see the abundance of ventilation area they've given it on the sides:

[image]

Comment: @John Do you mean to say printing continuously for 24 hours (unlimited paper and toner refills) is no problem because the printer is smart and does the rest thing, slowing down when it needs to?

Answer (score 8):

Something else: I would be leery of printing that many pages in one batch unless you have just installed a high yield toner cartridge.  What happens when the toner runs out in the middle of the job?  Can you reprint only the bad pages?

Comment: +1 Good one! Does anyone know what happens in such a scenario?

Comment: Most printers will just stop before quality deteriorates. Once new tone is install they start off from where they stopped unless they were turned off in the mean time. You can usually take out the toner cart and give it a shake to encourage a few more pages out of it (sometimes many extra pages, though at that point you may find the output dims and/or bands more then usual). The main problem here is if doing manual duplex - things might get out of sync if the printer decides to reprint the last page upon restarting or such - but I recommend manual duplex is only done for small jobs anyway.

Comment: I've never had a laser simply stop before quality problems started to show up.

Answer (score 5):

It has these specs:

> Max. Monthly Duty Cycle: 30,000 pages &
>   Recommended Monthly Print Volume: 500
>   to 3,500 pages

So, I think you should be fine.  It will get heated up, but that is normal for a laser printer.  That is what fuses the toner to the paper.  It should heat up to its normal operating temperature and stay there.  It is kind of like miles on a car, it is wear and tear, but it doesn't matter that much if you put them all on it in a year or 10 years.

Comment: Shouldn't it be interpreted that max daily is 1500?

Comment: No, I don't think so, unless you saw that in the manual.

Answer (score 4):

You should take this amount of printing to a commercial printers - it would be cheaper and their equipment is designed to take the hit.
You will probably get away with it on a SOHO laser printer but it's not the best tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be an issue for a printer of this caliber, though it may result in more wear and tear than you'd want.

The monthly duty cycle limit is 30,000 pages, with a recommended monthly duty cycle of 500 to 3500 pages.  The sort of print job you're running can be very stressful on the printer; I'd suggest that you allow the printer to cool down for 10-15 minutes every 500 or so pages.

Note that the high-yield TN-650 toner cartridge has a specified yield of 8000 pages and the DR-620 drum unit has a specified yield of 25,000 pages.